# Distributional derivative of a continuous nonnegative function

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $f: [0,+\infty)\to H$ be a $C^1$ function such that $\lim_{t\to+\infty}f(t)=0$. Does $\|f(t)\|$ have a distributional derivative?
If yes, is it true to say that "if for some $t_0>0$, $\frac{d}{dt}\|f(t)\|<0$, then $\|f(t)\|$ is decreasing on a neghberhood of $t_0$"?

Comment: $g(t)=\|f(t)\|$ is continuous, its distributional derivative is well-defined. That at some point the limit $\lim_{h\to a} \frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}< 0$ exists doesn't mean that $g$ is decreasing on some neighborhood, try $-t + t^2 \sin(e^{1/t})$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Let me ask my question better: if the distributional derivative of a function is nonpositive on an interval, can we say that the function is non-increasing on that interval?

Comment: Yes, $g' \ast n \phi(n.)$ will be smooth and its derivative will be $ \le 0$ on a subinterval. If $g(b)> g(a)$ since $g$ is continuous for $n$ large enough we'd have $g \ast n\phi(n.)(b)>g \ast n\phi(n.)(a)$, contradiction. There is the definition of positivity of a distribution on an interval : for all $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(a,b),\varphi\ge 0\implies \langle T,\varphi\rangle \ge 0$